# Round of the number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I have this number $$4.6150777119$$ 
Which is the one that results if I round with two digits? I think is $4.62$ but I do not have the theory to justify it.
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The number you gave is closer to $4,62$ than to $4,61$ or to any other number rounded with two digits.  Hence your answer is correct.